# how to set value from textwatcher to specific multiple textviews in android

Tags: android, textwatcher

In this project i am adding some dummy data to autocompletetextview.. i am selecting some items from search and after i tried to add the quantities [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4xly.png)in this its working after selecting one item.... But if i select multiple items and tried to add quantities only the last text view is updating....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlj3u.png) like this... please help me on this... thank you :)

1.this is inside for loop when I select another item if I change the quantity of the previous item but recent total is updating instead of
            previous quantity.
2. here I am setting total value by calculating quantity unit price and
       tax and storing it in total textview

**This is My ListView Adapter Class**

```
 public class ListViewItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<ItemsBean> itemsBeanArrayList;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;



    public ListViewItemAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ItemsBean> arrayList){
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        itemsBeanArrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsBeanArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return itemsBeanArrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow,viewGroup,false);

        noo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_noo);
        itemnames = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_names);
        taxx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_taxx);
        up = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_up);
        qntyy = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_qntyy);
        down = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_down);
        unitp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_unitp);
        totall = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_totall);

        //noo.setText(i+1);
        noo.setText(""+itemsBeanArrayList.get(i).getSr_No());
        itemnames.setText(""+itemsBeanArrayList.get(i).getItemName());
        taxx.setText(""+itemsBeanArrayList.get(i).getUnitTax());
        up.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp);
        qntyy.setText(""+itemsBeanArrayList.get(i).getQty());
        down.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp);
        unitp.setText(""+itemsBeanArrayList.get(i).getUnitPrice());
        totall.setText(tot+"");

        num = Integer.parseInt(noo.getText().toString());
        item_name = itemnames.getText().toString();
        tax = Float.parseFloat(taxx.getText().toString());
        unit_pri = Double.parseDouble(unitp.getText().toString());
        total = Double.parseDouble(totall.getText().toString());

        final int pos = i;

        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(qntyy.getText().toString());
                System.out.println("////////////qnty num/////////// num " + num);
                if(num == 0 || num < 0 ){
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"please enter something",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
                else {
                    num = Integer.parseInt(qntyy.getText().toString());
                    if(num == 0){
                        qntyy.setText((num + 1) + "");
                    }
                    System.out.println("////////////before click/////////// num " + num);
                    qntyy.setText((num+1) + "");
                    num = Integer.parseInt(qntyy.getText().toString());

                    if(num != 0) {
                        tot = calc(num,unit_pri,tax);
                        itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).setTotalPrice(tot);
                    }
                    else{
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"please enter greater then 0",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    System.out.println("///////////////////////////// total " + itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).getTotalPrice());
                    totall.setText("" + tot);
                }
            }
        });

        down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(qntyy.getText().toString());
                if(num == 0 || num < 0){
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"please enter something",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
                else if(num == 0 || num == 1){
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"Least Quantity should be 1",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
                else {
                    num = Integer.parseInt(qntyy.getText().toString());
                    qntyy.setText(""+(num - 1));
                    //qnty_no = Double.parseDouble(qntyy.getText().toString());
                    if(num != 0 ) {
                        tot = calc(num, unit_pri,tax);
                        itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).setTotalPrice(tot);
                    }
                    else{
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"please enter greater then 0",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    System.out.println("///////////////////////////// total " + tot);
                    totall.setText("" + itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).getTotalPrice());
                }
            }
        });

        qntyy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                if (editable.toString().length() > 0 || editable.toString().equals("0")) {
                    //qntyy.setText("1");
                    qnty_no = Double.parseDouble(qntyy.getText().toString());
                    qnty_tot = Double.parseDouble(qntyy.getText().toString());
                    tot = calc(qnty_no, unit_pri, tax);
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>> TOT >>>>>>>>>>>> " + tot);
                    itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).setQty((int) qnty_no);
                    itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).setTotalPrice(tot);
                    totall.setText(itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).getTotalPrice() + "");
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>> itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).getTotalPrice() >>>>>>>>>>>> "+itemsBeanArrayList.get(pos).getTotalPrice());
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>> qnty_tot >>>>>>>>>>>> " + qnty_tot);
                    //System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>> TOT >>>>>>>>>>>> " + tot);
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    //CALCULATE TOTAL
    private double calc(double qnty,double unit,float tax){
        double addtot = (qnty * unit)*(tax/100);
        System.out.println("///////////calc////////////// addtot " + addtot);
        System.out.println("///////////calc////////////// tax/100 = " + (tax/100));
        System.out.println("///////////calc////////////// qnty " + qnty);
        System.out.println("////////////calc//////////// unit " + unit);
        double tot = (qnty * unit)+addtot;
        System.out.println("///////////calc//////////// total " + tot);
        return tot;
    }
}
```

> In this MainActivity i am creating autocompletetextview and calling the list view adapter... to get data... i am getting everything but in textwatcher if i enter any quantity after adding so many items its not working properly... as i explained above

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //HIDING ACTION BAR
    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
getItems();



    searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(itemsBeanArrayList,this);
    autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
     listViewItemAdapter = new ListViewItemAdapter(this,searchedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewItemAdapter);

    searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ItemsBean clickedObject = (ItemsBean) searchAdapter.getItem(i);

            autoCompleteTextView.setText(clickedObject.getItemName());
            searchedItems.add(clickedObject);

            listViewItemAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    });
}
```

For Dynamically printing i used this for loop inside a method

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < searchedItems.size(); i++ ){

        LinearLayout displayll = new LinearLayout(this);
        displayll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        displayll.setLayoutParams(rootParams);
        displayll.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

        TextView itemN = new TextView(this);
        itemN.setText("" + searchedItems.get(i).getItemName());
        itemN.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        itemN.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        itemN.setLayoutParams(textParams);
        displayll.addView(itemN);

        TextView qnty = new TextView(this);
        qnty.setText("" + searchedItems.get(i).getQty());
        qnty.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        qnty.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        qnty.setLayoutParams(textParams);
        displayll.addView(qnty);

        TextView pricee = new TextView(this);
        pricee.setText("" + searchedItems.get(i).getUnitPrice());
        pricee.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        pricee.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        pricee.setLayoutParams(textParams);
        displayll.addView(pricee);

        TextView totall = new TextView(this);
        totall.setText("" + (searchedItems.get(i).getQty() * Integer.parseInt(searchedItems.get(i).getUnitPrice())));
        value = (searchedItems.get(i).getQty() * Integer.parseInt(searchedItems.get(i).getUnitPrice()));
        totall.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        totall.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        totall.setLayoutParams(textParams);
        displayll.addView(totall);

        billLayout.addView(displayll);

    }
```

Comment: Please explain your requirement more and add the whole code including textviews

Comment: I have even given the screen shots please help me on this.... tahsinRupam

Comment: Where is your for loop ? Sorry, couldn't find that. Are you generating multiple qntyy as well as textwatchers dynamically ?

Comment: i hv added for loop with adapter class full ocde...please verify it...               Have u checked the images....?

Comment: I am traveling currently, will check your code later. I will let you know If I can find a solution.

Comment: i just used holder with list view and problem solved..... Thank you for your time :)